# Get info about background music from another app

Tags: swift, avaudiosession, mpmusicplayercontroller, background-music

I'm wondering if there is a way to get track info for an audiobook playing in the background via `Audible` or song playing via `Spotify` while I'm inside my app.

Right now I know that I can detect if there is background music playing:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying
```

I also know that I can get a lot of info about the music played through the official Music app:

```
MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem!.title
MPMusicPlayerApplicationController.systemMusicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don’t think you’re able to access any info about other applications’ playback other than whether or not it’s happening (`AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying`). To get more info, I believe you have too interface with each application’s data individually using their own SDK.  [Here’s a link to Spotify’s](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/ios/quick-start/).